# MongoDB difference between $orderby and Sort

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to fetch the latest document, which obviously is a single document, thus `findOne` should work fine. But `findOne` here returns the first document inserted. So I have two options now either use `$orderBy` with `findOne` or use `.sort()` function with `.limit()` in `find()`

Using $orderBy it would look something like:

```
db.collection.findOne({$query:{},$orderby:{_id:-1}})
```

And using sort:

```
db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
```

Both work fine, I just wanted to know which query should I prefer here? In terms of performance, or does both of them work the same way internally and there is no such difference between the two.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As of Mongo 3.2, `$orderby` is [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/).

The [docs explicitly say](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/):

> The $orderby operator is deprecated. Use cursor.sort() instead.

Unfortunately, `findOne()` doesn't support the `sort()` method, so you'll need to switch to `find()`:

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({'key': -1}).limit(1)
```

This will return a `cursor`, so you'll then need to pull the first result from the cursor.

Comment: To replicate using findOne with the `sort()` method instead of the deprecated `$orderby`, you can call `.next()` on the cursor at the end of this chain.

The full equivalent of:

`db.collection.findOne({$query: {}, $orderby: {_id: -1}})`

compatible with Mongo 3.2 is:

`db.collection.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1).next()`

Comment: If array of results is needed - just add `.toArray()`, like this: `db.collection.find({}).sort({'key': -1}).limit(1).toArray()`

Comment: At least for now, the wording in the documentation is: _Starting in v3.2, the $orderby operator is deprecated in **mongosh**. In **mongosh**, use cursor.sort() instead._ why just for mongosh?

Answer (score 22):

They are the same and in fact the documentation page for [`$orderby`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/)  actually talks mostly about the `sort()` function that is provided.

These [query modifiers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-modifier/) that allow you to add sections of a query on without using the functional accessors do exist but there is a bug mixing these two together so I would recommend you pick either the query modifiers or the functional methods and stick to that option.

In attempting to provide example code I have also found out one other thing when I looked at your question again. You provide:

```js
db.collection.findOne({"$query":{},"$orderby":{ "_id": -1 }})
```

But it is good to note that:

```js
db.collection.findOne({}).sort({ "_id":-1})
```

Actually produces:

> 2014-07-31T04:59:50.183-0700 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sort'

and as you can see here by my test data set:

```js
> db.rooms.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ad206e1d8f2d8351182830"), "id" : 1, "from" : ISODate("2014-06-26T00:00:00Z"), "to" : ISODate("2014-06-28T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ad276f1d8f2d8351182831"), "id" : 1, "from" : ISODate("2014-06-24T00:00:00Z"), "to" : ISODate("2014-07-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ad28ad1d8f2d8351182832"), "id" : 1, "from" : ISODate("2014-06-20T00:00:00Z"), "to" : ISODate("2014-06-28T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ad28c61d8f2d8351182833"), "id" : 1, "from" : ISODate("2014-06-20T00:00:00Z"), "to" : ISODate("2014-07-03T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ad29971d8f2d8351182834"), "id" : 1, "from" : ISODate("2014-06-20T00:00:00Z"), "to" : ISODate("2014-06-21T00:00:00Z") }
```

the answer is actually correct:

```js
> db.rooms.findOne({ "$query":{}, "$orderby":{ "_id": -1 }})
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53ad29971d8f2d8351182834"),
        "id" : 1,
        "from" : ISODate("2014-06-20T00:00:00Z"),
        "to" : ISODate("2014-06-21T00:00:00Z")
}
```

So it is interesting to note that query modifiers are supported by `findOne` where as functional accessors are not, which could be a reason to use query modifiers instead.

Comment: To clarify: the reason that `find` supports `.sort` while `findOne` does not is that `find` returns a cursor object, which has a `.sort` method defined on it that determines the order in which documents are returned (and which can only be set before the cursor has started returning batches of documents). `findOne` returns zero or one documents. *Which* document gets returned is determined by who is first according to `$orderBy` if it's set. Otherwise it's [natural order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/), which is the order of the documents on disk.

Comment: @wdberkeley indeed forgot to mention that findOne didn'tm return a cursor thanks