# MongoDB Querying in Angular App to Handle Sorting By Date and Element Match

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, angular

We have been using the mongoDB $elemMatch feature to pass a query via POST requests in our Angular app. This has been working as expected, returning results that match to the passed fields and values, like so:

```
body: any = {"consulting.process": { "$elemMatch": { "status": "initial", "completed" : false } }};
```

We're changing our implementation to now match to one field/value, AND to the most recent startDate. In other words, I need to loop through an array of objects and return ONLY the items that match for `status: initial` BUT ALSO only when the object's date value is the most recent date in the array.

Just wondering if there's a way I can modify the above query to handle that, or if there's a different MongoDB method to use here?

By the way, when I try this, it does return results:

```
body: any = {"consulting.process": { "$elemMatch": { "status": "initial", "startDate" : Date } }};
```

... but I'm not exactly sure what it's evaluating here? Just the presence of a date value? Or is some sort of default sorting happening here on `Date`?

Very specifically I need to return results where "status" is === "initial", but ONLY if the startDate is the most recent one in the array.

Here's an example of what the objects in the array look like:

```
           [
            {
                "status": "initial",
                "endDate": "2017-04-16T09:00:29.081Z",
                "startDate": "2017-03-02T20:10:24.105Z",
                "_id": "2"
            },
            {
                "status": "processing",
                "endDate": "2016-04-16T09:00:29.081Z",
                "startDate": "2015-03-02T20:10:24.105Z",
                "_id": "1"
            }
           ]
```

I want a query that returns for the correct "status", and only if that object with the correct status ALSO has the most recent "startDate" among the array of objects.

Comment: It's just looking for a date value. You're looking for a query like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058007/mongodb-difference-between-orderby-and-sort note: You'll want to set a Limit of 1 and OrderBy date

Comment: You'll have to use the aggregation framework here, Would you mind posting some sample data?

Comment: Sure. Added an example of the data structure above.

Comment: To address the most recent dated object change you can store the records in descending sorted order. This way you can simply check for first object and look for its status. Something like `db.collection_name.find( { 'consulting.process.0.status': "initial" } } )`

Comment: That's a good idea, Veeram. Will look into that. Thanks.